# Displaying multiple rows in a single View using Details Scaffolding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, .net-4.5

i have an employee details table, where i have a column called Role. Each employee can have more than one role. Currently following is the recordset that I am getting from SQL which i want to display in MVC 4 using DETAILS as scaffolding.

Emp_ID   |       Emp_Name     | Role

E101 |       Employee1    | Primary

E101 |       Employee1    | Secondary

So how to write LINQ and View Code for this.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Have model class for Employee

```
public Employee
{
   public int EmployeeID{get;set;}
   public string EmployeeName{get;set;}
   public string Role{get;set;}
}
```

In Controller:

```
public ActionResult List()
{
    DataSet ds=db.GetEmployees();
    var emp=( from t in ds.Tables[0].AsQuerable()
              //replace column names correctly with your db columns.
              select Employee{ EmployeeID=Int32.Parse(t["EmployeeID"].ToString()),
                               EmployeeName=t["EmployeeName"].ToString(),
                               Role=t["Role"].ToString()}).ToList<Employee>();
    return View(emp);
}
```

Add View with  "List" cascading type  which is strongly typed to Employee model which will automatically generate view model.

View:

```
    @model IEnumerable<Models.Employee>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "view";
}

<h2>view</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EmployeeID)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EmployeeName)
        </th>
<th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Role)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmployeeID)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmployeeName)
        </td>

        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Role)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Comment: can we add mixed scaffolding in any view of MVC 4.like i want do display details of a single record and the multiple rows details too